# Why does pixel quantization in matplotlib seem to work differently for lines and points?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to partition some data in a graph into four quadrants and I get a funny behavior near the boundaries. Here's a simple example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

np.random.seed(123)
xy = np.random.randn(100000,2)
ofs = 6.0
x0 = 0
y0 = 0
x = xy[:,0]
y = xy[:,1]
w = 2
plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
f = plt.plot
for k,color in [(0,'green'),
                (1,'red'),
                (2,'orange'),
                (3,'yellow')]:
    sx = (k&1)*2-1
    sy = (k&2)-1
    ii = ((x-x0)*sx>=0) & ((y-y0)*sy>=0)
    f(x[ii]+ofs,y[ii]+ofs,'.',markersize=w,color=color)
f(plt.xlim(),[y0+ofs,y0+ofs],'--k',linewidth=w)
f([x0+ofs,x0+ofs],plt.ylim(),'--k',linewidth=w)
```

[image]

The dots and the lines are the same width, so while I would have expected the dashed lines to show up with red/orange/yellow backgrounds (since those dots are plotted last), why is it that I can see orange and yellow *below* the dashed lines? ("below" = vertically below, not z-order below)

Comment: Hard to read that code (a very different style from mine), but to me it looks the dashed lines are plotted last.

Comment: Yes, but why would that make any difference? The lowest orange and yellow dots have the same y-coordinate as the horizontal dashed line.

Comment: Ah, i misinterpreted your *below*.

Comment: some rounding issues ?

Comment: That's over the top for me, but a quick glance showed it's really hard to grab info about those internals (centering, radius vs. diameter and co). For [line2d](https://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html) there is ```markersize``` and ```linewidth```. Maybe you should be consistent too in regards to that. Also interesting is the doc-string: ```markersize: float```, ```linewidth: float value in points```. But i'm only guessing.

Comment: I can produce the same picture as you.
But when Ii enlarge the window, the picture is enlarge too and the artefact  disappears.

Comment: I would consider this to be a bug. Since version 2 matplotlib has somehow lost accuracy when it comes to plotting. I guess you can find a more minimal example for this and post an issue at matplotlib GitHub issue tracker.

Comment: *more* minimal example? it was tough enough to find this one.